# Programming for iOS with older Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm pretty new to coding for iOS and i have a question about setting up my development components.

I have MacBook Air with 10.5.8 Leopard on it. So we question is: will I have no problems writing apps having iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with XCode 3.1.4 for Leopard (10.5.7)? Will the created app work on all iphone versions? There is a possibility to upgrade to mountain lion and use newest xcode, but is it worth it ? Considering that I firstly have to upgrade to snow leopard and then to mountain lion.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: The app will work on all iPhones, but Apple won't let you submit apps built with the old SDK to the store. So you should update to the latest XCode.

Comment: I believe you can save a few coins if you burn the ML image on dual-layer DVD and perform a clean install instead of system update (probably requires to format a partition). Or actually if I remember correctly i was able to perform the ML `update` with one of Macs not wiping the system after updated SL to the latest available version.

Comment: "There is a possibility to upgrade to mountain lion and use newest xcode, but is it worth it ?" ... Are you serious with that?

Comment: It isn't really the version of Xcode that matters, rather the version of the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send them to the app Store, the apps have to be compiled with the latest iOS (right now iOS6), so you can't compile them with xcode 3.1.4.

You need lion to download xcode 4.5 that includes the iOS 6 sdk

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the configuration of your MAC Machine is not compatible for latest Mountain Lion OS. Even if it supports Lion OS, that itself will be a great deal.

Anyways, Using leopard, you can develop applications only upto **iOS ver 3.2**. So you would not be able to submit your applications to App Store untill you compile it with latest SDK.

For this you need atleast Lion OS (Better if you upgrade your hardware compatible with Mountain Lion). So that you can install latest XCode (Currently Ver 4.5). It will allow you to develop fully featured iOS application with latest features as well as upload them to Apple App Store.

Hope it helps. Let me know if anything else required.